# How do I get the values of other columns in the row when an event is raised from a mat-select drop down?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Using angular 7 material I need to get the data for all elements in the row of a mat-table in (during) the `selectionChanged` event of the mat-select drop down.  I can get the selection that changed in the event handler, but I need the values from other columns in the same row in the event handler.  Being new to angular I don’t see how to get the data. How do I get the values of other columns in the row that the event was raised from?

**.html**

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="onNotesChange($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of predefinedNotes" [value]="item.id">
          {{item.value}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
</td>
```

**.ts**

```
onNotesChange(event:any){
     console.log(event);
}
```

Other answers only show the drop-downs new value, I need other values from the row. For instance there is a usreId column I need the value of in the same row as the mat-select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" click)="selectDataRow(row);">
```

This fires before the `mat-select` selection change event so I was able to save the row in the component for access in the click event.

```
selectDataRow(row:Employee){
    this.dataRowClicked = row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `[value]="item.id"` with `[value]="item"`

Try like this:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of predefinedNotes" [value]="item">
     {{item.value}}
</mat-option>
```

Comment: that gives only the mat-select object.  looking for the entire row of data from the table/data source

Comment: Share it in stackbiltz

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner approach would be to pass the row object and the selected value in the same call by creating a map:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of predefinedNotes" [value]="{element: element, value: item}">
```

And in your function you can extract both items:

```
onNotesChange(event: MatSelectChange) {
  const value: { e: ElementType; v: ItemType } = event.value;
  const element = value.e; // This is the row object
  const item = value.i; // This is the selected mat-select object
  ...
}
```

I don't know what your types are so I just put in placeholders. You don't have to strongly type it but I like to if possible.